# mod_rewrite is not passing GET parameter?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^event/(.+)$ event.php?t=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

What I'd like is `./event/<stuff>` to redirect to `event.php?t=<stuff>`. This rule is not working, however.

The redirect does occur -- the file event.php is ran successfully, but the parameter `t` is lost somehow. This worked fine on my local dev server, but in production it's failing.

EDIT: Renaming event.php to evt.php and modifying the .htaccess causes a 404, so I think it's the second line that's causing event.php to render.

I've tried adding `Options -MultiViews`, but this makes every page a 404. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you remove the last line and just enable `MultiViews`? Your rewrite rule is only going to fire for non-existent URIs starting with  "event/" anyway

Comment: Sure. But sadly that hasn't fixed the event/ rule.

Comment: I'd just forget about extension-less URIs for now and focus on getting your app working.

Comment: note that second RewriteRule is not affected with previous RewriteConds